# How to fix System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException in Xamrin google maps

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I'm setting the Xamarin.Forms.GoogleMaps on my Xamarin app , but when i try to display the map I get a "application is in break mode" status 
with an Unhandled Exception:

System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.

I've tried Initiliazing it from the App Delegate class (which I'm not sure i've done properly)
I tried both in xaml and xaml.cs but still did not budge. Same error.

```
using Xamarin.Forms.GoogleMaps;
public partial class Discover : ContentPage
    {
        public Discover ()
        {
              InitializeComponent ();
                  Map map = new Map();
                  StackLayout layout = new StackLayout();
                  layout.Children.Add(map);
                  Content = layout;
        }      
        }
```

What i need to happen is get a map to appear and everything to compile.

### ---------------------------- FIXED -----------------------------------------

The problem was in the android execution , when adding the API to the nugetPackages you need to add some code aswell.

This is what I added to the android OnCreate method :

```
Xamarin.FormsGoogleMaps.Init(this, savedInstanceState);
```

So after I did that I'm good to go.

Comment: Please show the code where this exception happens

Comment: after the  public class MainActivity : 
            LoadApplication(new App(wholePath)); method is started

Comment: I'm sorry, but without any relevant code, it will be pretty hard to say what is going on. I suggest pinpointing the cause more specific and add that to the question.